# How to hide all the li elements in html after a certain no. of li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 10 li listing, want to hide after 3 list

```
<li> Test1 </li>
<li> Test1 </li>
<li> Test1 </li>
Click for more
```

After click on more show all 10 list.

Comment: Have a look into the [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) css selector. Update your question if you have a probelem implementing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
<script>
jQuery('ul li:nth-child(3)').nextAll('li').hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use css `nth` selector. No need to use JavaScript for that:

```css
ul li:nth-child(n+4){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
<ul>
```

Using **jQuery**

```js
$('ul li:gt(2)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

```js
$('#ul li:gt(2)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='ul'>    
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li></ul>
```